# How to upload iOS application to App-Store from other Account?

Tags: ios, app-store

I wrote some iOS application and used my private license:

- Development Provisioning Profile
- Distribution Provisioning Profile
  ...

I used TestFlight with list of devices, so far so good.

My application has bundle ID: `org.fess.phone`

So now I need upload this application to App-Store with different account lets say new company that in the past uploaded several applications and have different Distribution Provisioning Profile with bundle ID:  `com.some.company`.

I logout from iTunes Connect and login with new account info (mail + password) and see the list of old applications that company uploaded.

What should be my steps to upload my application?

When i try to register my application to new account, i get "You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps."

Thanks for help,

Comment: you need to register your bundle id with developer.apple.com

Comment: register your bundle id there, login with your developer profile, give it description and a bundle identifier. It's buried in there with your profile/SDK/certs, etc. App ID's is what it's called I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You'll need to change the bundle ID to `com.some.company.appname`.
2. You'll also need an login and a developer certificate on the new account.
3. Create a new App Store distribution profile for the app and install it and the cert on your machine.

If this is a individual account you can then submit to Apple. If it's a corporate account only the Team Lead can submit.

Comment: I have company  account and I want only to use it to upload to App-Store, nothing else, thanks

Comment: You can't submit without the App Store distribution profile for the account/app.